# Why do the Variables not update in this program?

Tags: python, tensorflow

So, I have this bit of code:

```
graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():
    res  = tf.Variable(
        np.zeros((100, 100), dtype=np.float32)
    )

    mask = tf.placeholder(np.float32, (100, 100))
    res = tf.add(res, mask)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(100):
        x1, x2, y1, y2 = np.random.randint(0, 100, 4)
        x1, x2 = sorted((x1, x2))
        y1, y2 = sorted((y1, y2))

        c_mask = np.zeros((100, 100))
        c_mask[x1:x2, y1:y2] = 255

        new_pic = sess.run([res], feed_dict={mask:c_mask})[0]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.imshow(new_pic.astype('uint8'), cmap='gray')
fig.show()
```

Basically, it (at least is supposed to) draws 100 random white rectangles on a black field. But what I get is this:

[image: WTF]

I do not understand. It looks like every iteration `res` just resets to bing a black slate again (the rectangle on the picture is the last one drawn, judging by the coordinates). Am I not saving it somehow, or what is it that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these two lines:

```
res = tf.add(res, mask)
##
new_pic = sess.run([res], feed_dict={mask:c_mask})[0]
```

to

```
update_op = res.assign(tf.add(res, mask))
##
new_pic = sess.run([res, update_op], feed_dict={mask:c_mask})[0]
```

---

A tensor should me modified with [Variable.assign()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#assign).

While you intended to update the tensor "res", the first line doesn't update it but only creates another tensor, and the **name** "res" is assigned to the new tensor. Hence the original res is never updated.

Comment: That makes sense, yes, thank you. I did not expect that there could be any difference between rewriting and modifying a Tensor, but it seems logical.